# how do I get a List of Key values in ParameterMap (Spring)

Tags: java, spring, dictionary

I hava a ParameterMap set that has completely different parameters in different scenarios

What i need is a String Array of "keys" in the ParameterMap

The closest i have got is using reportParams.toString();
Here is what i used to get the folowing output

```
ParameterMap reportParams = context.getRequestParameters();
System.out.println(reportParams.toString());
```

// The Output

map['username' -> 'user', 'decorate' -> 'no', 'decorator' -> 'empty', 'ajax' -> 'true', '_eventId' -> 'refreshReport', 'VEFactorSelection'-> '1', 'campusAndFaculty' -> array['111', '113', '115', '118', '112', '114', '116', '117', '21907', '21908', '99040', '99010', '99100', '99230', '99240'], '_flowExecutionKey' -> 'e4s1', 'reportLanguage' -> '3', 'date' -> '2013/06/20', 'nameType2' -> '1', 'confirm' -> 'true']

So what i want as end result is

username, decorate, decorator, ajax, _ecentId, VEFactorSelection, campusAndFaculty, _flowExecutionKey, reportLanguage, date, nameType2, confirm

I have Tried this

```
ParameterMap reportParams = context.getRequestParameters();

final List<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();

for (final Object o: reportParams.asMap().keySet())
names.add((String) o);

final String[] array = names.toArray(new String[names.size()]);

System.out.println(array[0]); // this part is just to see if i get output
```

End result of above code:

=================================== org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'org.hibernate.mapping.Map' for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.hibernate.mapping.Map] for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

=============================== Some extra's

Here is the API for "ParameterMap" http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/api/org/springframework/webflow/core/collection/ParameterMap.html

Comment: From the API doc you linked, there doesn't seem to be an `asMap()` method for `ParamterMap`. It is a part of the `MapAdaptable` interface, which is implemented by `LocalParameterMap` and `MockParameterMap`. But then the code shouldn't have even compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would do it

```
     Map<String, String> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, String>(parameterMap.size());
            for (Map.Entry<String, String[]> entry : parameterMap.entrySet()) {
                if (entry.getValue().length > 0) {
                    result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()[0]);
                }
            }

Set<String> nameSet = result.keySet();
String[] namesHolder= new String[nameSet.size()];
nameSet.toArray(namesHolder);
```

You have it in `namesHolder`

Edited answer. Try this

Comment: org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'org.hibernate.mapping.Map' for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.hibernate.mapping.Map] for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found

Comment: have changed the answer, i think it should solve, if its not a multivalued map

Comment: @ line 1 i get this compile error:__             The Type map is not Generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <String, String>

Comment: @ line 2 i get these compile errors:__
             -Map.Entry cannot be resolved to a Type
             -The method entrySet() is undefined for the type ParameterMap

Comment: Thx got it to work , error somehow origionated from somewhere else

Comment: great..i didnt check the code for compile errors, just wrote it

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ParameterMap reportParams = context.getRequestParameters();
Set<String> keys = reportParams.asMap().keySet();
```

Comment: Yes____
org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.util.LinkedHashMap' to required type 'org.hibernate.mapping.Map' for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type [java.util.LinkedHashMap] to required type [org.hibernate.mapping.Map] for property 'readOnlyConfiguredExporters': no matching editors or conversion strategy found